# How to update Maps SDK (version 18.0) in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, mobile, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin.Android. I am trying to update the Google Maps SDK for Android (version 18.0.0), which is now available via Google Play services. However, all the documentation on updates use build.gradle and change the dependencies to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.0` , which Xamarin doesn't have. How do I update the Maps SDK in Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin creates and maintains Xamarin.Android bindings for Google Play Services Google also offers a native mapping API for Android. The Maps API is suitable for cases where you want to maintain more control over the mapping experience.
Things that are possible with the Maps API include:

- Programmatically changing the viewpoint of the map.
- Adding and customizing markers.
- Annotating a map with overlays.

Unlike the now-deprecated Google Maps Android API v1, Google Maps Android API v2 is part of [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview). A Xamarin.Android app must meet some mandatory prerequisites before it is possible to use the Google Maps Android API.

Several steps need to be taken before you can use the Maps API, including:

- Obtain a Maps API key
- Install the Google Play Services SDK
- Install the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps package from NuGet
- Specify the required permissions
- Optionally, Create an emulator with the Google APIs

For more details, you can check:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api#install-gps-sdk .

and

https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have been using the Maps API by following those steps but it is an older version. I don't see the new 18.0.0 version mentioned to be updated to in NuGet. The latest version I see is 17.0.1. Is there something I need to do to NuGet in order to see 18.0.0 or do  I wait until that shows up in NuGet to install that version?

Comment: Yes,we just have to wait patiently for the new release of this nuget. Thanks for your support for xamarin.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Google requires this upgrade to version 18.0.0 be completed by March 2022, my question is will the xamarin nuget be updated in the near future?

Comment: You can keep an eye on the release log to be notified of new releases.

Comment: Any news about the release yet? NuGet still points to version 17 and not 18, and March is just around the corner!

Comment: you need install new VS 22, there you will find android 12(monoandroid12).