# Update API Maps SDK for Android 18.0.x in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hi guys, me again, context: the project where i'm working use API Maps for android  with the package Xamarin.Forms.Map and i need to update to the version 18.0.x because we received a email with the new version and it will be default in march (we are also interested for the new features to) (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer#how_to_try_the_new_renderer) end of context, so i need to kwon how update because the documentation is for JAVA and KOTLIN and they use build.gradle to change the dependencies but xamarin doesn't have that. Also if you can say what other changes will be necessary for the new renderer i will be glad with you guys.

P/D: I see in [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69841802/how-to-update-maps-sdk-version-18-0-in-xamarin-android) the answer says i need to use the nuget package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps but in my case i use the Xamarin.Forms.Map (Project already create) is necessary migrate to Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps?

P/D 2: I'm new in Xamarin pls be patient with me <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything for now. Yes, there is a new renderer in Maps and it will be the default one.

However, the e-mail doesn't state that you have to update the Maps SDK to a newer version. Only if you want to try the new renderers right now.

You will have to wait with trying the latest Maps SDK as Xamarin has very few resources to keep all those bindings up to date, but it will come.